# Why my StringReplace don't work?

Tags: string, autohotkey

I want to replace the comma character into another based on order `Chr`

```
^Numpad4::
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard,%Chr(44),%Chr(45), All
Return
```

But why I cannot use it?Are any wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a command's parameters you have to use expression syntax:

```
^Numpad4::
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, % Chr(44), % Chr(45), All
; MsgBox, %clipboard%
Return
```

Without the percent sign **and the space**, Chr(44) is a literal string.